# AWS linux - How could I install postgreSQL on amazon linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, postgresql, aws

I want to install postgreSQL on Amazon linux.

Please let me know what I should type in regular sequence.
I saw some of questions about installing postgreSQL on linux, but there is no example about amazon linux. Most of examples used `apt-get` command. But amazon linux has not `apt-get`.

Also I want to use postgreSQL in python and django.

Comment: Look for documentation for Amazon Linux. `apt-get` is Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: AMIs are CentOS/RH based. No use looking to Debian instructions. They also have got Ubuntu images.

Comment: Amazon Linux is based on RadHat. Use **`yum`** for package-management. Visit [User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/managing-software.html) for managing software on aws linux.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL 9.5 isn't available in the AWS repos yet, but for 9.4:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install postgresql94
```

[Source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/now-available-amazon-linux-ami-2015-09/)